# .NET method with puzzling behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a method that works in mysterious ways.

Running this works fine;

```
FindConcept("Product");
```

Running this produces an (unwanted) different result, even though the value of SelCatID is "Product";

```
FindConcept(SelectedCategoryID);
```

Where the SelectedCategoryID looks like:

```
 protected string SelectedCategoryID
 {
     get
     {
         if (Request["c"] != null)
         {
             string c = Request["c"];
             ViewState["SelectedCategoryID"] = c;
             return c;
         }

         if (ViewState["SelectedCategoryID"] != null)
         {
             string cid = ViewState["SelectedCategoryID"] as string;
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cid))
             {
                 return cid;
             }
             return "";
         }
         else
             return "";
     }
}
```

This leads me to believe that there must be some weird side-effect in the get-method of the SelectedCategoryID object. I am new to .NET , so I don't have a good idea of how ViewState works.

I've tried debugging this in numerous way, for example I've tried this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SelectedCategoryID);
FindConcept(SelectedCategoryID);
```

Where the debug.writeline will produce "Product", which should mean FindConcept behaves as expected.

This has left me completely puzzled. How should I continue to tackle this problem?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you are putting in Product and getting out Product.  Isn't that what you want?  Where is your setter on SelectCategoryId?

Comment: This behavior can only be explained with the code inside `FindConcept`.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in your Get method.  What's happening in your webpage when you're running this code - what has the user done?

Comment: Should "Product" be coming from the second if statement, somehow you pass in a variable called SelectedCategoryID and that shows up in the hashmap as a name?

Comment: @Cyberdrew: Sorry, was unclear, edited the original post. Is the setter relevant? Seing as how I am only calling the getter method in this context?
@Daniel Hilgarth: Is it really? Eventhough I know that passing the appropriate string should work? I'll post it up asap anyhow, just have to make it appropriate for posting first.
@Dan Puzey: What's happening is that a dropdown list should be generated with the right options, when the string "Product" is passed in , it works, with the string object SelectCategoryID, an empty dropdown list is created.
@James Black: Correct.

Comment: In your `FindConcept` method do an `Assert` and see if you are being passed correct value.

Comment: You may also want to verify that there is no trailing whitespace in the resulting value.   Having a value of "Product " looks a lot like "Product" but could have different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewState in ASP.NET webforms is written out to the html as a hidden form field (encoded, and typically encrypted).

This means that viewstate will be available on postback requests, but not be available across an http redirect.

In the code above, it looks like the code is trying to handle both post backs and other types of requests - because it uses the indexer for the Response property which

> Gets the specified object in the Cookies, Form, QueryString or ServerVariables
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item%28VS.71%29.aspx

One likely scenario is that you are redirecting without passing along the information using one of the above methods, which means view state is not available, and the information is also not available in the url query string or cookie etc.

**Edited - Example**

There are many ways this could look, here is a simple example:
For example, suppose on one page you retrieve the "SelectedCategoryID" from the database in a GridView.  Under default scenarios, this would be stored in the Gridview of the page, and would be available in the viewstate when posting back to the same page (see http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=18  and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

However, suppose on a button click you did something in response to a button click such as

```
Response.Redirect("SomeOtherPage.aspx")
```

In this case, the ViewState on "SomeOtherPage.aspx" will not hold the value, so your getter is going to look for the value in other places, such as the url.  In this case, you could pass the "SelectedCategorID" along with something such as

```
Response.Redirect("SomeOtherPage.aspx?c=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(selectedCategoryId));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to admit this sounded like ancient greek to me, could you give me an example of how this could help me solve my problem?

Comment: @Emil - Edited answer to give example